# ng-packagr is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I got a legacy library that I am trying to put up to date and compile.

The build command I use is the following:

> ```
> "build:lib": "npm i && npm run lint && ng-packagr -p ng-package.json && node ./copy-lib-assets.js",
> ```

Everything runs fine until it gets to the **ng-packagr** part.

Then I get the following error:

> ng-packagr is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I have installed ng-packagr using the following commands:

> npm install ng-packagr --save-dev

The install completed with the following result:

> + ng-packagr@5.5.0
>   updated 1 package in 58.506s

Yet I still get the exact same error when I try to compile the project.

I know that it is probably a problem with the Environment Variables.
But after search on the whole computer I cannot find any executable related to ng-packagr.

Does anyone have a clue about why ng-packagr is not found?

Comment: I am facing the same issue at the moment! Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue and resolved it buy running below command

```
npm install -D ng-packagr
```

make sure opencollective-postinstall is also installed

Answer (score 1):

```
npx ng-packagr
```

may also be helpful. https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx